# Test Automation tool for Data Analytics Software

Tags: desktop-application, test-automation-architecture

I have been using Selenium for web application testing and need to switch to desktop automation testing which has process improvement functionalities like data analytics algorithms, etc. What could be the best tool to use for desktop software built using java?

Comment: 1 - There is no "best" tool, it will depend on your context. 2 - What have you tried so far? What were the positive and negative points you felt so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Selenium, there is [Winium](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2018/06/winium-a-selenium-based-windows-automation-tool/) that might be interesting:

> Winium is a Selenium based tool for testing and automating desktop applications on the Windows desktop. It is easy to use for those who are familiar with Selenium.

It is practically Selenium for Windows.

Comment: The questioner didn't say it was on Windows.

Comment: So? This answer might not answer questioners' particular need (we don't know that yet) but it might be helpful for those who wish to test Windows apps.

Comment: I understand your point, but Stack Exchange is meant to be precise in both questions and answers. Otherwise I could answer Java questions with the equivalent in Python, Ruby, etc, "to be helpful to those who wish to" use these languages. You could have commented the questions, asking for more info about which environment we are talking about.

Comment: I don't think your Java question analogy is valid. It would be if the asker asked for let's say Linux automation and I gave them Windows answer, but they didn't specify.

Comment: I thought about Winium but the desktop is implemented on java Swing and Winium doesn't support this framework. :(